# Apache Camel and InfluxDB 2.x

Tags: java, apache-camel, influxdb

Up to now I used Apache Camel (JAVA) to route data from an Apache Kafka broker to an InfluxDB 1.8. Now I upgraded the database to InfluxDB 2.5.

The two InfluxDB-Versions are incompatible in terms of their read/write API. For example, it is not possible to inject the required security token required for reading/writing.

InfluxDB 1.8 requires a dependency to

```
<groupId>org.influxdb</groupId>
<artifactId>influxdb-java</artifactId>
<version>XXX</version>
```

InfluxDB 2.5 requires

```
<groupId>com.influxdb</groupId>
<artifactId>influxdb-client-java</artifactId>
<version>YYY</version>
```

In Apache Camel an InfluxDB component is available:

```
<groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
<artifactId>camel-influxdb</artifactId>
<version>ZZZ</version>
```

Which has a dependency to the `influx-client`library. Does that mean there is no InfluxDB 2.x component anymore? How do I build an InfluxDB 2.5 endpoint then?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up building a custom Camel component providing native support for InfluxDB 2x in a separate Maven project. As a starting point I used the structure and code from original Apache Camel InfluxDB jar-file.

As a route for those who want to do something similar:

Create a Maven project with a POM like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<!-- NOTE: I would like to get rid of this camel parent and replace it with our own. didn manage yet -->
<parent>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>components</artifactId>
    <version>3.19.0</version>
</parent>

<groupId>my.group.name</groupId>
<artifactId>my-component-name</artifactId>
<version>3.19.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>Camel :: InfluxDBClient</name>
<description>A Camel Component</description>
<url>...</url>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- InfluxDB driver dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.influxdb</groupId>
        <artifactId>influxdb-client-java</artifactId>
        <version>${version.influx-java-driver}</version>
        <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
               <artifactId>logging-interceptor</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- test dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-test-junit5</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    ...
```

Create the following methods in your Camel component project (all based on original camel-influxdb), where prefix `Influx2Db` can be replaced with something to you liking:

- CamelInfluxDbException
- Influx2DbComponent (replace InfluxDB with InfluxDBClient (2.x) and adjust code)
- Influx2DbConstants
- Influx2DbEndpoint
- Influx2DbOperations
- Influx2DbProducer (replace InfluxDB with InfluxDBClient (2.x) and adjust code)

Create a file named `<last part of your package name>` at:

- `src/main/resources/META-INF/service/<package name minus last part>/<last part of your package name>`

with content:

```
class=<package name>.Influx2DbComponent
```

Furthermore, in your Apache Camel application you need Spring-Boot-Autoconfigure classes in your spring lookup path based on spring-boot-autoconfigure:influxdb (if you use Spring-Boot):

- Influx2DbAutoConfiguration
- Influx2DbCustomizer (FunctionalInterface)
- Influx2DbOkHttpClientBuilderProvider (FunctionalInterface)
- Influx2DbProperties

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, influxdb v2 has fully support only in `influxdb-client-java`. However according to documentation, you can use [InfluxDB 1.x compatibility API](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.5/reference/api/influxdb-1x/) to continue working with influx 2.X using `influxdb-java` lib.

Comment: Hi @Rustam, thanks for this hint. I tried this, but I failed as I was not able to pass the authorization token and the transaction threw an authorization exception. Maybe you can tell me how to pass the token through the compatibility API...?

Comment: Is this exception fault on camel lib? Did you use a token generated on influx 2.X?
Looks like problem in the request header. In Influx 1.x it is `Authorization: Bearer <myToken>`, in compatible Api `Authorization: Token INFLUX_API_TOKEN`. Looks like it is support only basic auth flow.

Comment: The second example is what I tried: I added the following line in my `.process(...)` method: `message.setHeader("Authorization: Token", <token from influxdb 2.5 as String>)`

Comment: If it is impossible using standard way and username/password logic also does not work, I do not have any clue how to login in this case

Comment: Well, I do have users and passwords in the database. But so far, when using the InfluxDB-CLI I always had to pass the token when interacting with the DB. That's why I thought it is a requirement to pass a token if I connect to the DB via Camel.